# Can not update GRUB due to syntax error /out of memory error

Tags: grub2, syntax

I have a dual boot with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm not able to update GRUB due to the following error

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-53-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-53-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-52-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
errore: out of memory.
errore: syntax error.
errore: Incorrect command.
errore: syntax error.
Errore di sintassi alla riga 296
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
```

Here below my `/etc/default/grub`

```
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

#GRUB_DEFAULT="Ubuntu"
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="light-gray/transparent"
GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="magenta/transparent"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="false"
```

You can also see my
`/etc/grub.d/*` files at the following [link](https://pastebin.com/u/vds89)

Thank you to everyone that can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with the following command:

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

because

```
sudo update-grub
```

was giving me the error at last line of the grub.cfg where the 40_custom file was located.

Hope this can help.

Comment: Then you had some sort of typo in yoru 40_custom. I did that once, looked at the .new file it create, but it said error was at end of file. Error actually was a missing closing } in one of the first boot stanzas. I had multiple boot stanzas in my  40_custom